# Can a QLayout hide, rather than resize, QWidgets?

Tags: qt, layout

I'm trying to implement a UI element which is composed of a bunch of sub-elements. They can grow or shrink as the parent does. Pretty straightforward `QLayout` stuff. However, when the parent gets too small, it hides a couple of sub-elements (which means there is now more room for the remaining elements, and they get a bit bigger).

I'm not seeing any way any of the standard `QLayout`s handle this. I guess you could think of the child widgets as having a priority, and low priority ones being hidden.

The layout is strictly horizontal, so is vaguely similar to a toolbar, except that there's no way to get to hidden items. (And the child elements aren't actions, as they would be in a QToolBar).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QStackedWidget.  I just started using them myself.

They have "pages" that are shown/hidden when called.  Eg:

`ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex( 0 );`

For example, when index 0 is showing, pages 1,2,3... are hidden underneath.

I've hooked up to bunch of radio buttons that when clicked show the appropriate page / widgets, and hide the others 'underneath'.  Connecting is simple:

```
connect( button_group_ptr, SIGNAL( buttonClicked( int ) ), ui.stackedWidget, SLOT( setCurrentIndex( int ) ) );
connect( ui.stackedWidget, SIGNAL( currentChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( stackedWidgetChanged( int ) ) );
```

Comment: I don't think that's the same thing -- the idea is that hiding widgets depends on the size of the container.